# Unsafe pointer manipulation vs MemoryMarshal.Write

Tags: c#, .net

I have some existing code using unsafe pointers to read & write basic types (short, int, long) to a byte array.

```
private static unsafe void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int value)
{
    fixed (byte* ptr = &buffer[offset])
    {
        *(int*)ptr = value;
    }
}
```

I'm looking to replace this with managed methods and I noticed MemoryMarshal.Write seems cover this use case.

```
private static void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int value)
{
    MemoryMarshal.Write(destination.AsSpan(offset), ref value);
}
```

(Note I'd probably change the method signature to use a Span in the long run but wanted something with the same exact signature for comparison.)

Assuming valid input (e.g. there is enough space in the array), is this guaranteed to have exactly the same result? From testing on various types (short, int, long) as well as structs it seems like these methods are equivalent, but I want to know about any unexpected corner cases.

Based on the discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/41418), it sounds like these are the same but it is not said explicitly.

I looked at the JIT disassembly [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0ASgK4B2wAllAKb4CS51ATgPYAOAyswG4UDG1CAG506OAGZcCbAGFsAb3TZl2JSrZMK3MMGq4kANmxkIYAGZ64AFmwB1TboBCAT10QAFACNX1ANoBdbE9iMwsmABpsCnJsFlCIamBI6OBsbQAbYmoASjVlRTQVIuwzCgAPagATbC8fACpsNmAmbABebAAyYNDmXzizBOB/XMLi/LyxlTr3FLrsppb2jKyRUbGAXwnNtdUdjS0dS0NcG3sKXQ42MFJa3QCgkLDkmP7B59TlnImCyewAWWoUBYTGcfzATAgAAswOl8GddF5Hsx8ABBCCXa7uV6JbKRJjUMxpGFZbKrIrbdZAA===). They are not exactly equivalent at least as far as out of range access is concerned, but I can't tell more than that.

Overall, the Span-based method also performs better in various benchmarks I've run on .NET Core 3.1. Expanding the use Span would also allow us to reduce heap allocations by replacing standard arrays with stackalloc arrays.

Comment: You can elide a check by explicitly sizing the span (which moves the size check into the construction): `buffer.AsSpan(offset, sizeof(int))`. This adds up especially if the method is inlined (which it normally would be). Of course, keeping the span around across method calls would be even better, but you've already mentioned an intent to move to spans entirely.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Nice. Will keep that in mind.